# JFrame issues with the action statements and specific methods

Tags: java, jframe

I am working a program that runs through a JFrame I have created and I am just having a few problems calling on certain methods in my code. The issues I am running a method that outputs something based upon evaluation, I keep getting nullpointers at the same spots.

```
    JButton btnDealCards = new JButton("Deal Cards");
    btnDealCards.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            displayYourHand.setText("");
            output = "";
            couples = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < hand.length; i++) {
                Card1 dealt = dealHand();
                if (dealt != null) {
                    hand[i] = dealt;
                    displayYourHand.setText(displayYourHand.getText()
                            + hand[i].toString() + "\n");
                } else {
                    displayYourHand.setText("NOT ENOUGH CARDS TO DEAL");
                    status.setText("Shuffle cards to continue");
                    return;
                }
            }
            // totalHand();
            // pairs();
            // twoPair();
            // threeOfAKind();
        }
    });
    btnDealCards.setBounds(336, 192, 98, 26);
    contentPane.add(btnDealCards);

    JButton btnShuffleCards = new JButton("Shuffle Cards");
    btnShuffleCards.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            shuffle();
            displayYourHand.setText("The Deck Has Been Shuffled");
        }
    });
    btnShuffleCards.setBounds(314, 229, 147, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnShuffleCards);

}

public void shuffle() {

    for (int first = 0; first < deck.length; first++) {
        int second = randomNumbers.nextInt(52);
        Card1 temp = deck[first];
        deck[first] = deck[second];
        deck[second] = temp;
    }
    btnDealCards.setEnabled(true);
}

public Card1 dealHand() {
    if (currentCard < deck.length)
        return deck[currentCard++];
    else {
        btnDealCards.setEnabled(false);
        return null;
    }
}

    public void pairs() {
    for (int k = 0; k < faces.length; k++)

        if (numbers[k] == 2) {
            output += "" + ("Pair of " + faces[k] + "'s ");
            couples++;
        }
    status.setText(output);
}
```

The first is my actionlistener and actionperformer and the next three are the actions I wish to preform that spit out the nullpointers. The issues are always the lines after the for loop such as the "status.setText(output);" or "btnDealCards.setEnabled(true);". I am thinking I need to turn these statements into return statements but that is my only idea. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables that are being dereferenced on the lines that are throwing the NullPointerException (NPE) are null. For instance, the status variable is null if you're getting a NPE on this line:

```
status.setText("Shuffle cards to continue");
```

and the displayYourHand variable is null if this line throws a NPE:

```
displayYourHand.setText("The Deck Has Been Shuffled");
```

and likewise the btnDealCards variable is null if this line throws a NPE:

```
btnDealCards.setEnabled(true);
```

My bet: you may be shadowing the variable by re-declaring it in a constructor or init method when you try to create the object, leaving the class field null. The key will be to look at the code where you *think* that you're initializing these variables and see why you're not in fact initializing them.

Comment: What does shadowing a variable mean? I have tried initializing btnDealCards to null in the local method and then trying to change it to true/false but I still get NPE. Is there something else I should be initialing the buttons as?

Comment: @Sam: Please read up here on [variable shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing). Don't re-set a variable to null in order to try to solve your NPE -- that makes no sense at all. You should be initializing your fields to whatever they are supposed to represent. A JButton variable is initialized to a JButton instance. Please show us as an *edit to your original post* where you think that you initialize the variables that are causing your code to throw NPE's.

Comment: Thank you hovercraft, I now understand where I declared the variables incorrectly causing the NPE, thank you for letting me ask stupid questions!

Comment: @Sam: You're welcome! And please don't confuse "stupid" with "ignorant". We're all ignorant when starting out in Java, and we're only stupid if we don't try to improve. Keep up the good work!